# Google Cloud Client Library for Java: insertInstance() results in an UnavailableException

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to create an instance using the Cloud API Client Library for Java. I have worked my way through the different Builder classes, using the "Equivalent REST" button in the console to see what items I might be missing, but now the call to `insertInstance()` is returning an UnavailableException. Checking in the console I see nothing was created. Who can help me find what I did wrong? All the URLs seem to be correct: when they are not I get a helpful exception with detailed errors.

The `SETUP_NO_BOT` constant is the text of my setup script, which creates a user, copies files from a bucket, that sort of stuff. That should not be the problem however, because then I would expect a running VM with errors in the startup logs.

All the examples I *could* find either used the older `com.google.api.services` packages or the `com.google.cloud.compute.deprecated` packages, and neither use a comparable class structure.

If I use the same code with a mistake in the URLs (now produced by `getUrl()` calls) I get a nice error return. This version consistently returns a 503.

```
    private Instance createInstance() {
        logger.debug("createInstance(): Creating boot disk based on \"{}\".", getBaseImage());
        AttachedDiskInitializeParams diskParams;
        if (ifSet(getBaseImageProject())) {
            diskParams = AttachedDiskInitializeParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSourceImage(getUrl(getBaseImageProject(), "images", getBaseImage()))
                    .setDiskSizeGb("10")
                    .setDiskType(getUrl(context, "diskTypes", "pd-standard"))
                    .build();
        }
        else {
            diskParams = AttachedDiskInitializeParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSourceImage(getUrl("images", getBaseImage()))
                    .setDiskSizeGb("10")
                    .setDiskType(getUrl(context, "diskTypes", "pd-standard"))
                    .build();
        }
        AttachedDisk disk = AttachedDisk.newBuilder()
                .setType("PERSISTENT")
                .setBoot(true)
                .setMode("READ_WRITE")
                .setAutoDelete(true)
                .setDeviceName(getName())
                .setInitializeParams(diskParams)
                .build();

        logger.debug("createInstance(): Creating network interface to network \"{}\".", getNetwork());
        AccessConfig accessConfig = AccessConfig.newBuilder()
                .setName("External NAT")
                .setType("ONE_TO_ONE_NAT")
                .setNetworkTier("PREMIUM")
                .build();
        NetworkInterface netIntf = NetworkInterface.newBuilder()
                .setNetwork(getUrl(context, "networks", getNetwork()))
                .setSubnetwork(getRegionalUrl(context, "subnetworks", "default"))
                .addAccessConfigs(accessConfig)
                .build();

        logger.debug("createInstane(): Creating startup script metadata.");
        Items metadataItems = Items.newBuilder()
                .setKey("startup-script")
                .setValue(SETUP_NO_BOT)
                .build();
        Metadata metadata = Metadata.newBuilder()
                .addItems(metadataItems)
                .build();

        logger.debug("createInstance(): Create the instance...");
        Instance inst = Instance.newBuilder()
                .setName(getName())
                .setZone(getUrl(context, "zones", context.getZone()))
                .setMachineType(getZonalUrl(context, "machineTypes", getMachineType()))
                .addDisks(disk)
                .setCanIpForward(false)
                .addNetworkInterfaces(netIntf)
                .setMetadata(metadata)
                .build();
        return gceUtil.createInstance(inst) ? gceUtil.getInstance(getName()) : null;
    }
```

createInstance is very simple:

```
    /**
     * Create an {@link Instance}.
     */
    public boolean createInstance(Instance instance) {
        logger.debug("createInstance(): project = \"{}\", zone = \"{}\".", getProjectName(), getZoneName());

        Operation response = instClient.insertInstance(ProjectZoneName.of(getProjectName(), getZoneName()), instance);

        return isHttp2xx(response);
    }
```

Comment: Managed to get it working. There were some urls on “global” within the project that should have been zonal. Also maybe of influence was the network interface having both a network as well as a subnet connection. Kind of annoying that it simply threw a 500-class Exception, rather than a proper error.